# Overwrite default system include directories using sysroot

Tags: gcc, arm, g++, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile for AArch64 `aarch64-linux-gnu-g++`. I specified sysroot using `--sysroot=/home/aaron/Sysroot_Debian-Buster`. However, when trying to `#include <signal.h>`, gcc is still trying to include the file from `/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/signal.h` instead of `/home/aaron/Sysroot_Debian-Buster/usr/include/signal.h` (I confirmed `signal.h` exist under this path). By adding `-v` parameter, I can saw that system-default directories have higher priority than sysroot. Is there a way to overwrite this order and force using sysroot?

```
... other include path in -I...
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/9
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/9/aarch64-linux-gnu
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/9/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/include
 /home/aaron/Sysroot_Debian-Buster/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu
 /home/aaron/Sysroot_Debian-Buster/usr/include
End of search list.
```

I tried to reinstall gcc cross toolchain, also tried using g++8, still got same issue.

Comment: `... other include path in -I...
` Hi, please post _full_ output from `gcc -v` including all command line options and exact gcc version.

Comment: There are several ways.  You can compile with `-ffreestanding` and then manually link the correct libraries.  Alternatively, you can use a custom spec file with `--specs`. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html  There are many other options like `-nostdlib`, etc.  However, I think the first two make the most sense for you as you have a completely different file system.  Also, you probably could have done this when configuring and building the compiler.